# Select in an ALTER table statement

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I am trying to reset the auto-increment after I deleted some rows but I want to get the last index. I get an error about my syntax when I try to execute it. Thank you!

```
DELETE FROM 'database'.'table' WHERE 'columname'='';    
ALTER TABLE abcID AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT MAX(abcID) FROM table)
```

Comment: Basically I want to take the value of that (SELECT MAX) and assign it to the auto-increment.

Comment: The single quotes are not correct.

Comment: That's not the spirit of `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Why do you think you need to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a (sub-) select or a user variable in DDL (data definition language) statements.

If you need to do that dynamically in SQL, you need to build a string, prepare and execute it (assuming table t1 and t2 with column a as auto_increment).

```
mysql> select @a:=CONCAT("ALTER TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT=", MAX(a)) FROM t2;
+------------------------------------------------------+
| @a:=CONCAT("ALTER TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT=", MAX(a)) |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| ALTER TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3                      |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> prepare my from @a;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> execute my;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```